# Can I cast a memory area with a class type?

Tags: c++

```
class RW {
    int a;
public:
    int read() const {
        return this->a;
    }
    void write(int _a) {
        this->a = _a;
    }
};

#define PHYSICAL_ADDRESS (0x60000000)
#define SIZEOF_PHY_ADDR  (sizeof(RW))
// assume physical memory area is already assigned for the sizeof(RW)

void main()
{
    int val;
    void *phy_ptr = PHYSICAL_ADDRESS;
    RW *rw_ptr = (RW *)phy_ptr;

    rw_ptr->write(1);
    val = rw_ptr->read();
}
```

Please assume that the code above is pseudo code.
I have a shared physical memory area which is read/writable. And I want to cast the pointer of that area to read and write. Can I do this and is it acceptable?

I have checked it works fine but I am not sure if it's right cpp manner.

I appreciate any response and discussion!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can and should use placement `new`

Comment: You shouldn't be using "C" style casts in C++ code, but watch this about "reinterpret_cast" : You might want to watch this "C++ Weekly - Ep 185 - Stop Using reinterpret_cast!" : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L06nbZXD2D0. TLDR: you can easily run into undefined behavior.

Comment: Do you have to initialize the memory? Is your class membervstructure simple (standard layout) as in the shown code? There are solutions for this kind of access that probably work now and solutions that definitely and are standards-compliant and defined behaviour. I would assume you are asking for the latter.

Comment: @Sebastian I don't initialize the memory. There are more data but basically it just read and write the member variables from the shared memory. So could you name the solutions or give me a hint to find them if you could?

Comment: To make this kind of operations defined behaviour in C++ http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0593r6.html was adopted into C++20. The very practical std::start_lifetime_as will only be available with C++23. Until then you can use placement new with the object type *or* with std::byte: new (start) std::byte[length]; the basic types char, unsigned char and byte implicitly create (class) types in a region of memory.

Comment: For this to work, your type must have a trivial default constructor (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) and destructor. They basically should do nothing. Then it is called an implicit-lifetime-type.

Comment: For destruction you can use std::destroy https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/destroy instead of delete as the best way. But as your destructor is trivial anyway, it should have no effect.

Comment: (Just) theoretically, the placement new could alter the memory. To (even in theory) make sure to conserve its value (if you need that) you would have to memcpy elsewhere, call placement new, memcpy back and call std::launder as a workaround, until start_lifetime_as is available (see chapter 3.8 of the linked C++ standards paper).

Comment: Since years lots of code is doing the memory casting in non-standards compliant ways. And it 'worked' (half accidentally, half by nicer behavior of the compilers than the standard demands.) But now there are efforts to clean it up. The main 'problem' is, if an object is not created at this memory location, it does not exist and the optimizer could not only optimize away all accesses, but even the parts of the program trying to access this memory. That part of the program could crash or show some totally undefined behaviour. So the lifetime of the object has to be started in an official way.

Comment: Dmitrys answer using placement new should work in a standard compliant way. Calling the destructor directly is an alternative to std::destroy.

Comment: @Sebastian I really appreciate your detailed information with nice explanation. I didn't understand them all fully since I need to read a lot to do so, but it seems your answer has the point that I wanted to know about cpp.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to cast: you may just create the object at that address with [placement new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) operator.

```cpp
void main()
{
    int val;
    void *phy_ptr = PHYSICAL_ADDRESS;
    //RW *rw_ptr = (RW *)phy_ptr;
    RW *rw_ptr = new(phy_ptr) RW;

    rw_ptr->write(1);
    val = rw_ptr->read();

    rw_ptr->~RW();
}
```

Comment: In this case should I also delete rw_ptr at the end? And could you explain why I shouldn't cast?

Comment: Because if you just use cast, new will not be called and you will not have a valid instance of your class.

Comment: @PepijnKramer okay, thanks for the replies I will research about instance and what additional thing it needs when the size of memory is already same to the class. Btw, calling delete gives me the abort in this case. so I should only use the new without delete.

Comment: In the end I almost never use this technique though, unless I have full control of the memory layout. Is the code that generated the  shared memory layout compiled with a different compiler and/or compiler settings? If so you probably need to implement proper serialization (https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization)

Comment: There is no placement delete operator. You allocate memory manually and provide the pointer explicitly, so you don't need to deallocate this memory using the `delete`.

Comment: @PepijnKramer it's actually a file and it will be read and write by the linux processes.